# Display only rows which are having a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Displaying rows having a particular class. using jquery is a simple task. I've just started working on javascript concept. I'm not able to display it by adding a class. Here is my code.

```
$("#tblAllMessages tbody tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

The equivalent of the same in javascript which I'm writing is.. But, its not working.I just need to check the tr's having the class and display them.

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
if(rows.className == 'active') {
     table.rows[i].style.display = 'block';
} else {
    table.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

It didn't work. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: If your row has more than one class, this won't work, as `className` would be something like `"class1 class2"` (use `indexOf` instead, or a regex). Also, there's a typo in your if statement: `row.className` (not `rows`). And apart from that, this looks like a task you should be using CSS for.

Comment: @christian314159.. Thanks for the info. I need to write in JS file. Can you make a small snippet for the same?

Comment: Sorry, are you going from jQuery to plain JS, or the other way round? I'm confused.

Comment: Exactly dear. I'm planning to write in plain JS.

Comment: Using classes in jQuery or JavaScript does not mean you are using OOPS concepts.

Comment: I'm using in the OOP concept. I didn't write all the code :) I have just mentioned a small snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is really confusing, i would do something like this:-

```
var rows=document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){

if(rows[i].className == 'active') {
     rows[i].style.display = 'inline';
} else {
    rows[i].style.display='none';
}

}
```

Comment: Let me check Mustafa.

Comment: It works.. But the alignment of the table rows gets disturbed. :(

Comment: No dear. Its the same :(. Can you help me how to use indexof in this case?

Comment: Sorry i made a typo, updating the source, run it and check

Comment: Its the same. UI gets disturbed

Comment: try now again, please

Comment: No dear. I hope I can send you the screen shot. I don't know why its working with jquery code but not with javascript.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. But, still not working for me. Thank you very much. Can you tell me how can I check number of records having a particular class using javascript? $('table tr').hasClass('classname').length can work in jQuery.  I need in javascript.

Comment: Actually the problem is with the display property, Since i cannot see your full code, cannot make sure whats going. The documentation of show() function says `If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.` So getting the exact previous display property will require your html code. In jquery it will automatically select the previous display property and set it .

Comment: To check number of records of particular class use, `document.getElementsByClassName('classname').length;`

Comment: I've checked with it. It says undefined.

Comment: Check if you have typed the function name correctly, copy paste the one I provided and try.

Comment: I've solved it. Thank you so much bro :) May I know your email ID so that I can be in touch with you?

Comment: I've sent an email to you. Kindly check it again.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is similar to yours, but works with `TR` tags that have more than 1 class:

```
for( var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++ ){
    if( table.rows[i].className.indexOf('active') > -1 ){
         table.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    } else {
        table.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

It would also show the row if there was a class like `is-not-active` though. If you were going for IE10+ support, you could use `classList` instead:

```
row.classList.contains('active')
```

If not and you'd like it to be more robust, `split` up `className` on spaces and check the resulting array whether it contains your class.

And you can achieve the same thing with CSS instead much easier:

```
#tblAllMessages tbody tr {
  display: none;
}
#tblAllMessages tbody tr.active {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but the UI gets disturbed. I mean its not the same when I use with jQuery.

Comment: Did you see the update I made changing 'block' to 'table-row'? This might have caused a rendering difference.

Comment: Let me check by adding in the css file. But, where should I use row.classList.contains('active')

Comment: I've checked it. No use Chritian. :( I wish I can send you the screen shot.

Comment: In regards to `classList`: `if( table.rows[i].classList.contains('active') ){`. But as mentioned, doesn't work in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

**CSS**

```
#tblAllMessages tbody tr{
display: none;
}

#tblAllMessages tbody tr.active{
display: table-row;
}
```